# Using the same code for both client and server

Tags: dart, dart-html

What makes it possible for client side code to share some server side code in dart? I know there are some packages where this is possible but what makes it happen? I haven't found much on this subject overall and wanted to minimize my code for future projects. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain it to me. Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently if you don't import `dart:html` or `dart:io` nor any library that imports one of these transitive, the code is platforms-independent. 
Importing `dart:html` ties the code to the browser, importing `dart:io` to the standalone VM (there are also the evolving Fletch and Flutter platforms).

There is ongoing work to make imports configurable so that imports import a different library, depending on where the code is executed. This should make it much easier to share libraries between such patforms.

Answer (score 2):

Have look at the [Wilt](https://github.com/shamblett/wilt) package for one example of how to do this, basically the environment neutral code is instantiated as either a client side(using dart:html), or a server side(using dart:io) client by the user of the package.
This method works well with utility packages that wrap HTTP interfaces, the way Wilt wraps the CouchDb HTTP protocol.